# How to remove dynamic field suffix like _i,_txt in solr while quering?

Tags: php, solr, elasticsearch, lucene

I am indexing data in solr with using dynamic field (Schemaless Feature).
Like I have some fields like **product_txt,id_i,category_txt** etc..

I want the above mentioned fields to be **product,id,category** in response while selecting from solr. Like want to remove the suffix _txt, _i from fields while returning from solr.

Is this possible in SOLR itself?. If yes,Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [field aliasing](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#Field_alias), but it requires you to list the alias for each field in the `fl` parameter:

```
product_txt:product,id_i:id,category_txt:category
```

Comment: I know this.But Is there any other solution at solr side itself will do this for all fields except that I would have to specify in fl paramaters manually??

Comment: No. Not that I know of. You can specify the `fl` list as a static value in the request handler definition (look at `<lst name="appends">` to use it by default without having to specify it in every query.

Answer (score 0):

I think anything cannot be done at solr end for this ..

You have to manually add some code at client side to remove the extra thing i.e suffix in your case.

like at java end you can use

```
String responseString = "product_txt";

String result = responseString.substring(0, responseString.lastIndexOf("_")) ;
```